# internet explorer not storing checkbox on back button php

Tags: php

I'm building a php multiple choice style application online as part of a survey tool for a project and it all seems to be fine apart from when I test inside internet explorer, no surprise there.

When I click the submit my answers button within IE the application then checks whether the user has entered the right answer or returns an error in an array.

the problem is that when I use the javascript go back -1 function the checkboxes are blank instead of being "Ticked". It works for every other browser.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rely on the browser vendors (IE, Firefox, Chrome etc) implementation for this behavior. Maybe in IE 10 this will work - maybe in Firefox 3.6 it won't etc.

If you want to persist your form values without posting the data via `POST` - you will have to store them in a cookie (or in newer browsers the local storage maybe).

I guess it would be better for your survey script to post the data and intercept forward/back submits on the server side.

Comment: so I would have to post the data and store it inside the mysql table agains the user and just update it on each submit button??

Comment: Yes - this is usually how it is done. In order to persists the state - you would not necessarily need to store the data on every post request. One could also store the serialized state (all form values that have been posted already) in a hidden variable (or cookie, session or localStorage).